# How to call a function of another indicator script?

Tags: function, call, pine-script, indicator

How can I use calculation results of one script ("indicator X") inside another script ("indicator Y")?

Indicator X looks like:

```
//@version=4
study("Indicator X", overlay=true)
a = input(title="Input A", defval=3)
b = input(title="Input B", defval=3)
```

I know how to create function inside that script:

```
my_function(a, b) =>
var float trend = 0
if (condBull)
    trend := 1
if (condBear)
    trend := -1 
[trend]
```

Can I call that function inside another script?

Somehow like this?

```
//@version=4
study("Indicator Y", overlay=false)
plot(my_function(2,2),title="Indicator X Trend line", style=plot.style_line, color=color.red)
```

Comment: There's no way of using items from another script. Only copy-paste the code of required function.

Comment: alright...copy paste. So I don't have to search further. Thank you!